# Combining dataframe column values (categorical and numeric)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df) with a number of columns, some of which contain categorical data and others which contain numerical data. I would like to define the value of column 'd' as the combination of the values from two columns ('a'& 'b') (one with categorical data and the other with numerical data).

e.g. column 'a' row 1 has categorical data value 'h' and column 'b' row 1 has numeric data value '76'. I would like column 'd' row 1 to then have the value 'h76'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include what you have tried so far with some reproducible code? Otherwise, this isn't a question, so much as a request (demand?) that some stranger do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
df$d <- paste0(df$a, df$b)
```

If like some people you don't like seeing too many `df$` you can also do:

```
df <- transform(df, d <- paste0(a, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dfrm$d <- apply(dfrm, 1, paste0)
```

This is might give unsatisfactory results if  some of the numeric columns have long decimal representations. You should really post a reproducible example, best done by editing your questions and inserting the output of `dput(head(datfrm))`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this.

```
mydatf$d <- factor(mydatf$a):factor(mydatf$b)
```

for example

```
a <- c('h','l','l','h','h')
b <- 1:5

factor(a):factor(b)

1] h:1 l:2 l:3 h:4 h:5
Levels: h:1 h:2 h:3 h:4 h:5 l:1 l:2 l:3 l:4 l:5
```

This is very different from the other answers in that it necessarily produces a factor as opposed to character variable.  It's also an introduction on part of what `:` does in modelling formulas later on.  For example, note what the levels of the variable are.  This might be the best answer, or a terrible one, depending on what you want this new variable for.  Also, if column `a` is already a factor you can change `factor(mydatf$a)` to just `datf$a`.  This is often the case in a `data.frame` object.

Comment: `:` is related to `interaction`, but the latter will coerce its arguments to factor.  `test$new <- interaction(test$a, test$b, drop=TRUE, sep='')` looks a lot like the `paste0` solution but returns a factor rather than character.

Comment: Yes it does. That's a good point and is another solution.  What I was trying to do was not provide a solution just like the others.  The questioner doesn't provide enough information to know the best solution.  Maybe `drop = TRUE` shouldn't be used.  If other features of interaction aren't necessary, levels shouldn't be dropped, and column `a` is already a factor then what I proposed would end up being most concise.

Answer (score 1):

John convinced me to enter this as a separate answer, even though it is highly related to his answer.

```
interaction(test$a, test$b, drop=TRUE, sep="", lex.order=TRUE)
```

This returns the same values as the following:

```
factor(paste0(test$a, test$b))
```

(And I think the factor levels will be in the same order as well, if test$a is unordered.)

Using a factor is usually preferred over character (but not always).